# How to implement failover cluster on windows server 2016`

Tags: asp.net, failover, windows-server-2016, failovercluster

I have a web application running on IIS-10 on Windows Server 2016. My requirement is to set up a two node failover cluster for my web application as shown in the figure below. Here initially Server1 is active and server2 is passive. By default all requests are sent to Server1. Request are sent to Server2 when Server1 goes to inactive mode.

[image]

I searched on the web but, Its not clear for me.

Please suggest a way to implement. Thanks in advance.